# How to generate report using report viewer which can contain bulk of data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reportviewer

I want to display a report which will generate as employee selected by grid view. If i select 'Select All' check box than all employee data should be through in report and if i select people randomly than only that people data will be produce in report.  Please help me out. I done report for single employee but for this i am not getting any idea. Thanks :)

Comment: Which report tool you used for generating report. Crystal report or something else.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called [setParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252663.aspx) in report viewer which is used to pass the data from .NET application to your report viewer .The below links may help you

[Pass Report Parameters](http://www.csharpcourses.com/2008/06/how-to-pass-parameters-to-reporting.html)

[Cascading Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337169%28SQL.105%29.aspx)